# Sending Notifications in the Background of a ReactJS Chrome Extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, socket.io, push-notification

How to Get Google Chrome Notifications without Opening the Extension?

Here's what I've tried so far:

Created a background script that runs continuously.
Attempted to use the chrome.notifications API to send notifications.
However, the notifications don't seem to work as expected. Is there a specific approach or best practice I should follow to send notifications in the background of a Chrome extension built with ReactJS? Are there any permissions or manifest settings I might be missing?

Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

`

```
const [notification, setNotification] = useState('');

socket.on('cronJobResult', result => {
    console.log('Cron job result:', result);
    setNotification(result);
    createNotification(result);
    });

function createNotification(message) {
    chrome.notifications.create({
    type: 'basic',
    iconUrl: 'images/icon.png',
    title: 'Reminder',
    message: message,
    priority: 2
    });
    }
```

`